# Previously set array variable using $_POST method is lost after checking button clicked using $_POST

Tags: php

please forgive my confusing title, here is my problem:

1. set an array variable through $_POST
2. check which button has been clicked and process the $_POST variable

What is in my code:

```
<?php
...
$user = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $_POST['user']));
...

$submit = isset($_POST['button']) ? trim($_POST['button']) : '';
   if ($submit == 'Confirm') {

        ...do something with $user;

   } else if ($submit == 'Cancel') {

        ...do something else with $user;

   }
?>
```

It appears that when the page is first loaded, $user has been set correctly, however, once the "Confirm" button is clicked, the $name array is lost and cannot be processed. Any idea of how to resolve this will be much appreciated! Many thanks.

Comment: where is `$name` array? and it is a good idea to store this lind of data in `SESSION` variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an Idea, you need to store it in [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php). it seems you get `$_POST['user']` from previous page/request. variable `$_POST` only used for passing variable between page, It will not exist anymore if you reload the page.

do it like:

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'] = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $_POST['user']));
```

Comment: Don't give `w3schools` link.

Comment: Because they having wrong codes. You have to give official php.net's link to user.

Comment: I just thought w3schools have easy/breief explaination.

Comment: Yeah but with wrong code. When OP tries their code, it will not run and OP will ask again here for help.

Comment: Thank you so much, much appreciated for the prompt response from you guys!

Comment: @Wil could i know what you want to send information since you can also do thing like this by html5 local storage and reduce load on server .. but first i want to know about information

Comment: Thanks NullPinter, what I am trying to do is to retrieve user input and present it in a confirmation page (i.e. $user=$_POST['user']) for user's review. Once confirmed, the information will be saved into a database, or the user will be brought back to the input page for amendments if Cancel is clicked. I am using $_POST to check which button (Confirmed or Cancel) is clicked.